# GitHub transfer repository - to new organisation and change repository name

Tags: github

I have a repository "foo" under organisation "aa". I created a new organisation "bb" and i want to transfer my repository "foo" to "bb" but also modify the name. Something like
github.com/aa/foo.git -> github.com/newaa/newfoo.git

Reading [transfer repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/transferring-a-repository) assumes that repository name remains without changes in the new organisation. Any suggestions how to transfer to a new org and also modify repository name? I afraid if i change name after i transfer it, then some links may became broken.

Comment: What "links" are you talking about? A repo is just a repo, it doesn't contain any "links".

Comment: @matt: I *think* cactus means GitHub forks. I'm not sure how GitHub handle this, but it's not related to Git itself - I'll snip off the tag here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transfer ownership, then change the name. Or change the name, then transfer ownership.

Both transferring ownership and renaming provide redirections from the old locations.

> When you rename a repository, all existing information, with the exception of project site URLs, is automatically redirected to the new name... In addition to redirecting web traffic, all git clone, git fetch, or git push operations targeting the previous location will continue to function as if made on the new location.

> All links to the previous repository location are automatically redirected to the new location. When you use git clone, git fetch, or git push on a transferred repository, these commands will redirect to the new repository location or URL. However, to avoid confusion, we strongly recommend updating any existing local clones to point to the new repository URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dec. 2022, you actually *can* transfer *and* rename!

> ### [Rename repositories while transferring them](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-12-rename-repositories-while-transferring-them) (Dec. 2022)
>
> Now admins can transfer and rename a repository at the same time.
> Before, each action was separate.
>
> In the transfer repository screen, choose “**`Select one of my organizations`**”.
> The “**`Repository name`**” field will appear below.
> You must be an admin on the target organization to rename the repository.
> Renaming isn’t available if you “**`Specify an organization or username`**”.
>
> Optionally change the name the repository will have after transferring.
> Then complete the transfer!
>
> Learn more about [transferring a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository).